# How do we shape Xarray data-array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-xarray

I have been working with x-array. How do we reshape the array? Is there any method like re-shape in NumPy?

```
temp = data['__xarray_dataarray_variable__'][:, :, :]
```

The above line of code selects all the 3 dimensions of the x-array. Ie the shape of the array is (5, 2, 1).
How do I change the x-array so that it is of the form (5*2, 1).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xarray syntax is a bit unintuitive. In any case, you can use stack for this:

```
temp = temp.stack(dim_new=['dim_0','dim_1'])
```

Assuming originally it was an xarray of shape `(dim_0: 5, dim_1: 2, dim_2: 1)`, temp will then become an xarray with dimensions `(dim_2: 1, dim_new: 10)`. You can further apply `temp.transpose('dim_new','dim_2')` to get it to (10,1) shape.

Comment: Here I added 0.01 to the values of xarray because earlier it showed that log of 0 is infinite.

Comment: So with your solution I could get my xarray in the required form but when I try to plot it, I get some wierd error. `plt.figure(figsize=(3,5)) data_slice = temp1[:, :]  xr.ufuncs.log(data_slice + 0.01).plot(cmap='magma', vmin=0, vmax = max_value*.7)`. Here I am getting the error ----> Plotting requires coordinates to be numeric or dates of type np.datetime64, datetime.datetime, cftime.datetime or pd.Interval. Also i cannot find the variable 'xarray_dataarray_variable' . How do I solve there errors.

Comment: I can't really tell without seeing your array and your code. It's likely there's some sort of formatting error. Can you try converting it to a numpy array and then plot?